# ID showing up as Unresolved reference in MainActivity.kt

Tags: android, kotlin

I have looked through many examples but i really cant figure this out. I literally just started working with Kotlin and android studio. Any help would be appreciated
Hey is my code:

#### activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_No"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:textColor="#1495d7"
        android:text="@string/Sign_in" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/FrgtPass"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/Frgt_pass_prmt"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.hackapp1

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      btnLogin.setOnClickListener{}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you did not apply `kotlin-android-extension` plugin.
It was applied automatically, but not now.
`kotlin-android-extension` has some issues. It will be deprecated in near future.
See details [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42121).

Instead of `kotlin-android-extension` ViewBinding and DataBinding is recommended.

You can simply enable like following:

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding { enabled = true }
    dataBinding { enabled = true }
}
```

See below links for details.

- [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)
- [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: @evening_star This code should be in app level `build.gradle`.

Comment: Yes I just added the extension there, and that worked like a charm. Thank you.